# How to do conditional rendering in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx, conditional-rendering

How to do conditional rendering in react native with more than 1 condition?

Following is some portion of  my code

**Index**

```
 .then(response => response.json())
          .then((responseData) => {
             this.setState({
           progressData:responseData,
          });
    .....
    ......
      render() {

        const { progressData }= this.state;
      return(
        <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <HeaderExample />
        <View>
         {progressData == "1"} 
               (<View>

                 <Text style={{fontSize:28,color:"#8470ff",fontWeight: 'bold',paddingTop:20,alignSelf:'center'}}>Pending</Text>

                </View>)}
{  progressData == "2" && 
           (<View>
             <CardSection>
             <Text style={{fontSize:28,color:"#8470ff",fontWeight: 'bold',paddingTop:20,alignSelf:'center'}}>InProgress </Text>

             <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
             <Button
             title="Report"
             color="#8470ff"
             onPress={() =>onPressReport()}
             />

             </View>)}
```

But here it is for a single case means if `responseData` contains only one field. But now the reponseData contains 2 arrays. Each with 3 objects. So how do I check conditional rendering here?My responseData looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRWSz.png). I want to populate some UI on each condition. That means `if status = 1 && work_type ="plumber"` then render some UI.
Also `if status = 2 && work_type="electrical" && assigend_to="worker_45"` then render some ui. So how do I do this?

Please help

Comment: Try `condition ? <MyComponent /> : null` instead of `condition && <MyComponent />`

Comment: So how do I map over each element here?

Comment: Why you want to map? How exactly ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can move your render in a new variable, or function. to keep clear the `render` function

```
 render() {

        const { progressData }= this.state;
      return(
        <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <HeaderExample />
        <View>
        {renderProgressData(progressData)}
        ... //rest of your code
      )
  }
```

and in your `renderProgressData` function you can create a `switch`

```
renderProgressData = (progress) => {
   switch(progress) {
    case 1:
        return (<View>1</View>)
    case 2:
         return (<View>1</View>)
    // ...  and so on
    default:
        return (<View>Default View</View>)
   }
}
```

It is a little cleaner in this way for me.